# Problem in the installation of R package rsvg

Tags: r, package, rsvg

I'm trying to install [r](/questions/tagged/r) package [rsvg](/questions/tagged/rsvg) without any success. Tried the following two methods:

**1**. **install.packages("rsvg")**

```
install.packages("rsvg")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is
  later:
     binary source needs_compilation
rsvg  2.3.1  2.3.2              TRUE

installing the source package ‘rsvg’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rsvg_2.3.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 183798 bytes (179 KB)
downloaded 179 KB

* installing *source* package 'rsvg' ...
** package 'rsvg' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
rm -f rsvg.dll rsvg.o
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/bin/x64/Rscript.exe" "../tools/winlibs.R" 2.48.8
Error in download.file(sprintf("https://github.com/rwinlib/rsvg/archive/v%s.zip",  : 
  download from 'https://github.com/rwinlib/rsvg/archive/v2.48.8.zip' failed
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(sprintf("https://github.com/rwinlib/rsvg/archive/v%s.zip",  :
  URL 'https://codeload.github.com/rwinlib/rsvg/zip/refs/tags/v2.48.8': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
Execution halted
make: *** [Makevars.win:7: winlibs] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rsvg'
* removing 'C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/rsvg'

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmG8xM2\downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rsvg") :
  installation of package ‘rsvg’ had non-zero exit status
```

**2**. **remotes::install_github("ropensci/rsvg")**

```
library(remotes)
install_github("ropensci/rsvg")
Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/rsvg@HEAD
  
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmG8xM2\remotes5a645f9057ed\ropensci-rsvg-6d9840f/DESCRIPTION'     
─  preparing 'rsvg':
   checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
   checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
─  cleaning src     
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories     
─  building 'rsvg_2.3.2.tar.gz'
  
Warning:
  
   Warning: file 'rsvg/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected
   Warning: file 'rsvg/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected

  
   

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'rsvg' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
rm -f rsvg.dll rsvg.o
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/bin/x64/Rscript.exe" "../tools/winlibs.R" 2.48.8
Error in download.file(sprintf("https://github.com/rwinlib/rsvg/archive/v%s.zip",  : 
  download from 'https://github.com/rwinlib/rsvg/archive/v2.48.8.zip' failed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(sprintf("https://github.com/rwinlib/rsvg/archive/v%s.zip",  :
  downloaded length 35551249 != reported length 43111940
2: In download.file(sprintf("https://github.com/rwinlib/rsvg/archive/v%s.zip",  :
  URL 'https://codeload.github.com/rwinlib/rsvg/zip/refs/tags/v2.48.8': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
Execution halted
make: *** [Makevars.win:7: winlibs] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rsvg'
* removing 'C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/rsvg'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmG8xM2/file5a645596780/rsvg_2.3.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

**sessionInfo()**

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] remotes_2.4.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] processx_3.8.0    compiler_4.2.1    R6_2.5.1          rprojroot_2.0.3   cli_3.4.1         prettyunits_1.1.1 tools_4.2.1       withr_2.5.0      
 [9] curl_4.3.3        crayon_1.5.2      callr_3.7.2       ps_1.7.2          pkgbuild_1.3.1
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the binary?

Comment: Yes, I tried `install.packages("rsvg", type = "source")` and got the same error.

Comment: Do you have the Rtools build chain installed?

Comment: Reiterating the first comment: Have you tried installing the binary? The code in your response (obviously) doesn't do that. R should ask if you want to build from source and you should click "No". CRAN hasn't build the binary for the newest version of the package yet but if you don't need the newest version, you can just use the existing binary. (Building from source works just fine on my system.)

Comment: @Roland: Yes I also tried installing the binary and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/ropensci/rsvg/issues/14), you should first install `pkgconfig` like this:

```r
install.packages('pkgconfig')
install.packages('rsvg')
library(rsvg)
#> Linking to librsvg 2.48.4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you experience some connection issues when installing the required winlib. You could also try to install this first:
`remotes::install_github("rwinlib/rsvg")`

EDIT: Same suggestion as the comment by @Limey

Comment: Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 404.
  Not Found